# Can you calculate the lenght difference between two people using the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

The length of men in a population is an average of 175 cm with a deviation of 10 cm. The lenght of the men shows a normal distribution. I take two men out of the population. What are the chances the the first man is more than 10% taller than the second man?
I tried to solve the question by making a new distribution with a means of 350cm and a deviation of 20 cm and then finding the chance that two men are longer than 367,5 cm, but I am not confident that this works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let those 2 men be X and Y. Then you are looking for $P(X > 1.1Y) = P(X - 1.1Y > 0)$. Notice that $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(175,\,100)$ and therefore, $Z' = X - 1.1Y \sim \mathcal{N}(175 - 1.1*175,\,100 + 1.21*100) \sim \mathcal{N}(-17.5,\,221)$.

Let $Z = \frac{Z' + 17.5}{\sqrt{221}}$, then Z is standard normal distribution and all you need is $P(Z' > 0) = P(Z > \frac{17.5}{\sqrt{221}})$

Comment: Thank you very much Snowball. I understand this. So I get P = 12%